# Oracle sequence.nextval returned no rows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sequence

I have this SQL script i my app:

```
select my_seq.nextval from dual connect by level <= 100;
```

It works great but once I saw (in logs) that it returned no rows at all. Value of sequence is quite far from maximum. I wonder how is it possible at all.

Sequence creation script:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq 
MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 
INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 3602281 
CACHE 2000 NOORDER NOCYCLE;
```

Comment: Could you post the sequence creation script? Also, what if you select `currval`? And can you run the `select` in SQL*Plus and it works, it only fails in your app?

Comment: Error happened a couple of days ago, so I can't do any tests right now. And it is working now. I'm sure it was DB issue but I need a proof to convince my boss that app works well.

Comment: To get 100 values of sequence at once.

Comment: As @JohnDoyle suggests, can you describe dual?  Is it sys.dual?

Comment: @tbone It's not declared explicitly, but AFAIK there's no local DUAL table in scheme.

Comment: @AndreiPetrenko just curious, do this: select owner from all_tables where table_name = 'DUAL';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small possibility that your `DUAL` table is empty or that you have a local `DUAL` table? Try:

```
select 1 from dual;
```

If no rows then try:

```
select 1 from sys.dual;
```

Comment: You can easily do: `create table myschema.dual(dummy varchar2(1));`. Or, if logged in as `SYS` or have the permissions: `delete from sys.dual;`.

Comment: So it would be much safer to replace DUAL with SYS.DUAL in script?

Comment: I would guess so as it would be very unusual for `SYS.DUAL` to be emptied (and it would generally only be DBAs who could do it) but always possible that someone could create a local version of it.

Comment: wow, never thought of this...scary to think of implications of a local empty dual table!